# Has Firebase a special Realtime table called metadata to store user metadata?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Following the documentation about [Control Access with Custom Claims and Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims), I can read this example:

```js
    // Set custom user claims on this newly created user.
    await getAuth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, customClaims);

    // Update real-time database to notify client to force refresh.
    const metadataRef = getDatabase().ref("metadata/" + user.uid);

    // Set the refresh time to the current UTC timestamp.
    // This will be captured on the client to force a token refresh.
    await metadataRef.set({refreshTime: new Date().getTime()});
```

Does it mean that **by default** there is a Firebase Realtime Database table called `metatadata` that contains information about the user? Or is it an example and I can use, for example, a Firestore collection to store this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in that page uses the Realtime Database to send a signal from the server-side code that updates the token to the client that it needs to refresh its ID token.

You showed the server-side code, but this is the client-side companion code for it from the same page:

```
metadataRef = firebase.database().ref('metadata/' + user.uid + '/refreshTime');
callback = (snapshot) => {
  // Force refresh to pick up the latest custom claims changes.
  // Note this is always triggered on first call. Further optimization could be
  // added to avoid the initial trigger when the token is issued and already contains
  // the latest claims.
  user.getIdToken(true);
};
// Subscribe new listener to changes on that node.
metadataRef.on('value', callback);
```

So this code listens for changes on the `metadata/$uid/refreshTime` path and forces a refresh of the ID token when that value changes, so that is always has the latest ID token with the latest custom claims that your server-side code sets.

There is nothing special about the `metadata` path in that database call, and you can use any path you like - as long as the the client and server agree on the path.

You can also use any other mechanism to signal the change from the server to the client.

Comment: Got it. So the database is used to refresh the client, because it is listening changes in that table. I can use a Firestore collection to achieve the same result. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, Firestore would work too. I might actually opt for FCM myself, to keep things free. Of course you won't get a delivery guarantee with that, but given that the token auto-refreshes every hour anyway that might be fine.